# Oracle Data Access Components for Oracle Client 11.2.0.2.1

Tags: wpf, oracle, odac

I have devloped a WPF application (NET 4.0) that connects with Oracle using Oracles Data Access Provider for .NET 4.0.

All works well but I'm having a bit of an issue getting things working on user machines.

The issue is the users already have Oracle 9 client installed for use by our company ERP to connect to Oracle 9i.

I have installed ODAC on the user machines but then find that they can no longer connect to the company ERP, although if I go to the cmd prompt I can successfully do a TNSPING and it reports its using the Oracle 9 client.

What am I doing wrong here, can the two co-exist, should I be removing the Oracle 9 client completely and the company ERP should be able to use ODAC??

Any help in this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work with Oracle client 10 and 11 on the same computer without problem.

It seems that you can specify a principal home (see here : http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10500_01/em.920/a96697/moh.htm)

Set the client 9 to be principal, then the connection to the ERP may work better.